Group header for Multi Level Grouping in Tabulator
I am using Tabulator 6.3 and have Multi Level Grouping set up. I have just two levels but the issue I am having is the second level has only a few groups, which results in the table being cluttered with group headers for the second group, the majority of which contain only one item. I do have a group header defined, but I'm not sure how to handle this situation. Is there a way to have it only add a group header if there is more than one item in the group?
